# MySQL and regular expression

Tags: mysql

I use PhpMyAdmin and would like to move a certain part of a string in all the cells of "Column 1" to "Column 2". The data in Column 1 looks like:

```
Column 1: Name1 Name2, Name3 Name4, Name5
```

I want to move make it look like:

```
Column 1: Name1 Name2
Column 2: Name3 Name4, Name5
```

Can SQL do this for me?

Comment: You do not need PhpMyAdmin to do this.  PhpMyAdmin is just a client which is able to connect to a (MySQL)database.  There are other clients which are much better.

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp_replace() to match and delete the part you don't want:

```sql
update mytable set
column2 = regexp_replace(column1, '^.*?,', ''),
column1 = regexp_replace(column1, ',.*', '');
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9166949c43a059929e9aa2d61b4fedb5).

---

Or don't use regex:

```
update mytable set
column2 = substring_index(column1, ',', -2),
column1 = substring_index(column1, ',', 1)
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2dcae/1).

Comment: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=9d1c81945cdb4ed60bb7c38e11dd8232) is  much nicer than _sqlfiddle.com_  (Just my opinion)

Comment: @luuk yeah. I am sentimental about SQLFiddle, but you're right. I posted a dbfiddle for a regex solution, which I actually had to use because SQLFiddle's MySQL version is only 5.7 (7 years old now!), which doesn't have regex support. SQLFiddle's also down more often than it's up. Time to cut it loose.

Comment: Thank you Bohemian! I noticed I needed some further help.

What I am trying to do is to move data from products in WooCommerce, Wordpress. The data in Column 1 is only interesting if the Post_type (Column 3) carries the value "product".

Next thing is that Column 2 exists in another table (Table 2). There is a unique ID for every input which links one input with another between Table 1 and Table 2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lars that's a different question, so you should ask a new question. Show your attempt at a query in the new question, which will likely use some parts of this answer. See also [What to do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).